# Web API 1 and routing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I made a project using web api 2, but then found out that the server is running 2003.  So I am now recreating the project using web api 1 (.net 4).

I am placing the routing in App_Start\WebApiConfig

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ContactApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{email}/{firstname}/{lastname}/{source}"
 );
```

The url I use is

```
http://localhost:64470/api/Contacts/GetId?email=user5@company.com&firstname=joe&lastname=user&source=wer
```

This worked fine in web api 2, but I get the following error
**The resource cannot be found**

Here are some pieces of the controller class

```
 public class ContactsController : ApiController
 public string GetId(string email, string firstname, string lastname, string source)
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your route template requires that the parameters {email}, {firstName}, {lastName} and {source} be in the URI path. Replace your route with the code below

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ContactApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);
```

And it should reach your GetId method - the query string parameters don't need to be specified in the route.

Comment: This didn't wok for me.  Is there a tool that will tell me where IIS thinks it should go?

Answer (score 0):

To call the action with the url you are using you will need to have a route of:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
);
```

Personally I wouldn't do this. I would just use the default route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

and then call the APi using the following url:

```
http://localhost:64470/api/Contacts?email=user5@company.com&firstname=joe&lastname=user&source=wer
```